# How to write a maths expression in terms of x in Java

Tags: java, math

I am trying to write a function that parses in 2 numbers e.g. coefficient 5 and power 3. I want the output response to be 5x^3.

```
public void Variable(double c, double p)
{
     coefficient = c;
     power = p;
}

public Expression derive() 
{
      System.out.print("Youre term is " + coefficient + "" + Math.pow("x",power));
}
```

What have I done wrong here? It's not accepting my "x" in the pow function. But I'm not sure how to have a simple letter in there?

Cheers

Comment: Do you want to simply output a string? Then `coefficient + "x^" + power` or am I missing something?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Don't talk about not working code that is not part of your question. And unrelated:learn about Java naming conventions. And learn to use meaningful names in the first place. Variable is a super meaningless name for example.

Comment: @Bob - You may like to accept the answer as well, if it helped you. See how to accept an answer -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.pow(double a, double b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) doesn't accept a string as its first argument. It expects a double for both the base and the exponent. That method is for calculating values based on the base and the exponent supplied.

> -> Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument.

Instead, what you want to achieve can easily be done without using pow() method.

Just display `coefficient + "x ^ " + power` to the console.

```
System.out.print("Your term is " + coefficient + "x^" + power);
```